# Scanner class NoSuchElement Errors

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, java.util.scanner, java-io

[Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYtpO.png)

Can't figure out why I'm receiving `NoSuchElement` errors as the build works perfectly on my PC but my Mac doesn't.
Not sure if it's an error with my code - referring to the issue where the Scanner is trying to read a line that doesn't exist. But surely it can't be as my PC runs it perfectly.

```java
package equipment;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Equipment
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String line;
        String description;
        int quantity;
        double value;

        try
        {
            Scanner scFile = new Scanner (new File("Stock.txt"));

            System.out.println("Product\tQuantity\tPrice");
            System.out.println("-------\t--------\t------");

            while (scFile.hasNext())
            {
                line = scFile.nextLine();
                Scanner scTokens = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("&");

                description = scTokens.next();
                quantity = scTokens.nextInt();
                value = scTokens.nextDouble();

                System.out.println(description + quantity + value);
            }
            scFile.close();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException f)
        {
            System.out.println("Error - File Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace? As in, the actual output from the exception.

Comment: Can't add the embedded image, hopefully the generated link works :)

Comment: That's fine in this case. But for future reference, don't post pictures of your code or error messages. Just copy-paste the actual text directly into the question.